# best way to filter two strings into 1 in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, filter, hidden-field

I am trying to figure out a way to filter two arrays into one based on guessing the letters within one o them.. so basically hangman.  But if I had

```
word_array = ["b", "u", "s", "b", "o", "i"]
hidden_array = Array.new(word_array.length, "-")

p hidden_array
```

I would want to then print to the console ["b", "-", "-", "b", "-", "-"] if "b" were guessed.  What would be a good beginner way to create this array that will change over time?  Should it maybe be a hash? Thanks!

Comment: What's the condition to remove u,s,o,i?

Comment: What the heck is `busboi`? Is that supposed to be a real word?

Comment: I'm assuming `busboi` is just an example, @TomLord! LOL

Comment: @Gopal the condition is being different from `b`. `b` was guesses and them the program may exhibit `b`, but not the other letters. Like in a hagman game, as the OP explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the solutions so far revolve around arrays, but don't forget a string is basically a *character array* anyway. Just use strings:

```
word = 'busboi'
guesses = 'bs'

word.tr('^'+guesses, '-')
# => "b-sb--"
```

The [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) method converts all letters in the first argument to the mapping in the second argument, so you can do things like ROT13, simple cyphers and such, or in this case use the negation feature `^` to invert the first set and replace all non-matching characters.

Comment: I like. `word.gsub(/[^#{guesses}]+/, '-')` is a variant.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, that also works, but `tr` is perfect for this job.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the found letters in an array and make a method to do the printing

```
word_array = ["b", "u", "s", "b", "o", "i"]
found_letters = []
def hangman_prompt(found_letters)
  word_array.map do |char|
    found_letters.include?(char) ? char : "-"
  end.join(" ")
end
```

Then you could use this in an input loop like so:

```
loop do
  puts hangman_prompt(found_letters)
  puts "what is your guess?"
  input = gets.chomp
  if word_array.include? input
    found_letters << input
  end
end
```

I'm using `Array#map` here which creates a new array of the same length. Each of the original array items are passed to the block, which determines how they could be copied to the new array.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks Max!  All makes sense to me except for the .join(" ") tagged on the end of the hangman_prompt method.  I've seen .join before.. just never on the end of a method definition.  Should be easy to figure that out though! looks like its just a shorter way to incorporate the needed .join

Comment: Yeah, that's just a syntactic trick I guess. The reason that's there is if you `puts` an array, it will have newlines which isn't what you want here. You could `print` it or join before `puts`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
word_array = ["b", "u", "s", "b", "o", "i"]
word_array_i = word_array.map.with_index { |e,i| [e,i] }                                                
#=> [["b", 0], ["u", 1], ["s", 2], ["b", 3], ["o", 4], ["i", 5]] 
p hidden_array = Array.new(word_array.length, "_")

until hidden_array == word_array
  puts 'make a guess'
  guess = gets.chomp
  if word_array.include? guess
    puts 'correct guess'
    ar = word_array_i.select { |arr| arr.first == guess }
                     .flatten.select { |e| e.class == Fixnum }
    ar.each { |e| hidden_array[e] = guess }
  else
    puts 'incorrect guess'
  end
  p hidden_array
  puts
end
puts 'game complete'
```

Key methods to research [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/) `Array#include?`, `Enumerator#with_index`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use arrays, just strings.

**Code**

```
def replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, guess)
  word.scan(Regexp.new(guess)) { hidden_word[Regexp.last_match.begin(0)] = guess }
  hidden_word
end
```

**Example**

```
word = "busboi" 
hidden_word = "_" * word.length
  #=> "______"

replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "a") # guess "a"
  #=> "______"
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "b") # guess "b"
  #=> "b__b__"                                            
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "r") # guess "r"
  #=> "b__b__" 
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "o") # guess "o"
  #=> "b__bo_" 
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "u") # guess "u"
  #=> "bu_bo_" 
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "s") # guess "s"
  #=> "busbo_"
```

To check if the hidden_word has been guessed:

```
def guessed?(hidden_word)
  hidden_word.count('_').zero?
end

guessed?(hidden_word)   
  #=> false
```

Let's permit one more guess.

```
replace_underscores(word, hidden_word, "i") # guess "i"
  #=> "busboi" 

guessed?(hidden_word)   
  #=> true
```

**Notes**

I've used the method [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a block that is executed for each match. Within the block the [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/MatchData.html) object is retrieved with the class method [Regexp::last_match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match). (Alternatively, one could substitute the global variable `$~` for `Regexp.last_match`. For details, search for "special global variables" at [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html).) The method [MatchData.begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin) is used to obtain the index of the character in `str` which is to be replaced by the letter just guessed.